# Could anyone help to index the below Query

Tags: index

```
SELECT ITEM.I_TITLE,ITEM.I_PUB_DATE,ORDER_LINE.OL_DISCOUNT 
FROM ITEM JOIN ORDER_LINE ON ITEM.I_ID = ORDER_LINE.OL_I_ID
WHERE OL_QTY = '&olQty'
AND I_SUBJECT = '&ISubject'
AND I_COST = '&ICost';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure do you want to create index key so you can create relations or force index keys on this statement but if you want to force it on this statement you can use this

SELECT *
FROM Table WITH(INDEX(Index_Name))

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Oncodeeater, i had to create indexes, managed it by creating index on both tables, didn't understand the concept of indexing before i post the question.. anyway, thanks a lo for your prompt reply and help. Cheers :)